# Display Array User Input from Function

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my code at the moment. It is a lottery game and I get user input for 7 numbers and do not allow duplicates (same goes with the random generated). I need to display the user's numbers and the winning random numbers at the end of the main next to LOTTO RESULTS and WINNING NUMBERS.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void getLottoPicks(int userNums[], int size);
void genWinNums(int winNums[], int size);

int main()
{
    const int size = 7;
    int UserTicket[size];
    int WinningNums[size];
    char selection;
    string name;

    do
    {
        cout << "LITTLETON CITY LOTTO MODEL: " << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "1) Play Lotto" << endl;
        cout << "q) Quit Program" << endl;
        cout << "Please make a selection : " << endl;
        cin >> selection;

        if (selection == '1')
        {
            cout << "Please enter your name: " << endl;
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, name);

            getLottoPicks(UserTicket, size);
            genWinNums(WinningNums, size);

            cout << name << "'s LOTTO RESULTS" << endl;
            cout << "----------------------" << endl;
            cout << "WINNING TICKET NUMBERS : " << endl;
            cout << name << "'s TICKET       : " << endl;

        }
        else if (selection == 'q')
        {
            cout << "You have chosen to quit the program. Thank you for using!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid selection. Please try again." << endl;
        }

    } while (selection != 'q');

    return 0;
}
void getLottoPicks(int userNums[], int size)
{
    for (int times = 0; times < size; times++)
    {
        int input;
        cout << "selection #" << times + 1 << ": " << endl;
        cin >> input;

        bool isNotDuplicate = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            if (userNums[i] == input)
            {
                 isNotDuplicate = false;
            }
        }
        if (isNotDuplicate == true)
        {
             userNums[times] = input;
        }   
        else
        {
             cout << "You already picked this number. Please enter a different number: " << 
             endl;
             times--;
        } 
     }  

}
void genWinNums(int winNums[], int size)
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    for (int times = 0; times < size; times++)
    {
        int i;
        bool isNotDuplicate = true;
        while (isNotDuplicate)
        {
            isNotDuplicate = false;
            i = 1 + rand() % 40;
            for (int j = 0; j < times; j++)
            {
                if (i == winNums[j])
                {
                    isNotDuplicate = true;
                }
            }
        }
        winNums[times] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just like you would with any other array, use a loop and just print each element on its own

Comment: Instead of using an array pointer/size pair in your function prototypes, you can use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) in C++11 onwards, something like `typedef std::array<int, 7> LottoNumbers;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you might be new to programming so here you go, your working program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void getLottoPicks(int userNums[], int size);
void genWinNums(int winNums[], int size);

int main()
{
    const int size = 7;
    int UserTicket[size];
    int WinningNums[size];
    char selection;
    string name;

    do
    {
        cout << "LITTLETON CITY LOTTO MODEL: " << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "1) Play Lotto" << endl;
        cout << "q) Quit Program" << endl;
        cout << "Please make a selection : " << endl;
        cin >> selection;

        if (selection == '1')
        {
            cout << "Please enter your name: " << endl;
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, name);

            getLottoPicks(UserTicket, size);
            genWinNums(WinningNums, size);

            cout << name << "'s LOTTO RESULTS" << endl;
            cout << "----------------------" << endl;
            cout << "WINNING TICKET NUMBERS : " << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                cout << WinningNums[i] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
            cout << name << "'s TICKET       : " << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                cout << UserTicket[i] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;

        }
        else if (selection == 'q')
        {
            cout << "You have chosen to quit the program. Thank you for using!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid selection. Please try again." << endl;
        }

    } while (selection != 'q');

    return 0;
}
void getLottoPicks(int userNums[], int size)
{
    for (int times = 0; times < size; times++)
    {
        int input;
        cout << "selection #" << times + 1 << ": " << endl;
        cin >> input;

        bool isNotDuplicate = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            if (userNums[i] == input)
            {
                 isNotDuplicate = false;
            }
        }
        if (isNotDuplicate == true)
        {
             userNums[times] = input;
        }
        else
        {
             cout << "You already picked this number. Please enter a different number: " <<
             endl;
             times--;
        }
     }

}
void genWinNums(int winNums[], int size)
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    for (int times = 0; times < size; times++)
    {
        int i;
        bool isNotDuplicate = true;
        while (isNotDuplicate)
        {
            isNotDuplicate = false;
            i = 1 + rand() % 40;
            for (int j = 0; j < times; j++)
            {
                if (i == winNums[j])
                {
                    isNotDuplicate = true;
                }
            }
        }
        winNums[times] = i;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is pretty easy to loop through an array. Maybe have a look at [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm) for more info on arrays.

Comment: Hey if you see this I just want you to know that you put a smile on my face by helping me. I was getting really annoyed and for some reason, that solution did not even cross my mind. thank you soo much dude!

Comment: done. This was my first time using this to post my own question lol.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the examples show "classic" C++, instead of the more modern variants.
So here's my take on your code :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

// compile time constant, in many C++ examples this is done with a #define/MACRO
constexpr int number_of_lotto_numbers = 7; 
constexpr char play_lotto_char = '1';       
constexpr char quit_lotto_char = 'q';

// use std::array instead of int values[]; since this has automatic bound checking!
// no reading/writing beyond array limits is allowed
// I use, using here to make code a bit more readable further down the line
// it lets code show intent instead of implementation
using lotto_numbers_t = std::array<int, number_of_lotto_numbers>;

// do not return arrays by passing arguments, just return an array
// don't worry about this making extra (class) copies c++ knows how to optimize this
lotto_numbers_t get_lotto_picks()
{
    lotto_numbers_t lotto_numbers;
    auto lotto_numbers_entered{ 0 };

    while ( lotto_numbers_entered < number_of_lotto_numbers )
    {
        int input{ 0 };
        std::cout << "selection #" << lotto_numbers_entered + 1 << ": " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> input;

        // use std::find for finding items in collections, if it finds the end of a collection then 
        // the value is not found.
        if (std::find(lotto_numbers.begin(), lotto_numbers.end(), input) == lotto_numbers.end())
        {
            // lotto number not found so add it
            lotto_numbers[lotto_numbers_entered] = input;
            lotto_numbers_entered++;
        }
        else
        {
            // lotto number already in array so do not add it but give a message
            std::cout << "You already entered this number, try another number" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return lotto_numbers;
}

lotto_numbers_t generate_winning_numbers()
{
    lotto_numbers_t lotto_numbers;
    auto lotto_numbers_generated{ 0 };

    std::srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    do
    {
        int new_number = (std::rand() % 40) + 1;
        if (std::find(lotto_numbers.begin(), lotto_numbers.end(), new_number) == lotto_numbers.end())
        {
            // number not yet found
            lotto_numbers[lotto_numbers_generated] = new_number;
            lotto_numbers_generated++;
        }

    } while (lotto_numbers_generated < number_of_lotto_numbers);

    return lotto_numbers;
}

void play_lotto()
{
    char selection{ 0 };    // always initialize variables!
    std::string name;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "LITTLETON CITY LOTTO MODEL: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "---------------------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1) Play Lotto" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "q) Quit Program" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Please make a selection : " << std::endl;
    
        std::cin >> selection;

        if (selection == play_lotto_char)
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter your name: " << std::endl;
            std::cin.ignore();
            std::getline(std::cin, name);

            auto picked_numbers = get_lotto_picks();
            auto winning_numbers = generate_winning_numbers();


            std::cout << name << "'s LOTTO RESULTS" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "----------------------" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "WINNING TICKET NUMBERS : " << std::endl;
        
            for (const auto number : winning_numbers)
            {
                std::cout << number << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::cout << name << "'s TICKET       : " << std::endl;
            for (const auto number : picked_numbers)
            {
                std::cout << number << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;

            if (picked_numbers == winning_numbers)
            {
                std::cout << "you have won!" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else if (selection == quit_lotto_char)
        {
            std::cout << "You have chosen to quit the program. Thank you for using!" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid selection. Please try again." << std::endl;
        }

    } while (selection != quit_lotto_char);
}
```

Don't hesitate to ask questions on this code if you have any :)